# Need to get capturing image current orientation

Tags: android, cordova

Hi In my android phonegap app,when i capture the image in portrait mode then image is rotated when retrieving the image.

Here is my code to capture the image:

```
navigator.device.capture.captureImage(captureSuccess, captureError, {limit: 1});
```

If i set correctOrientation as true nothing difference.

If i use the below code then image is stored in correct orientation but saved in cache.Is there any solution to save in DCIM\Camera path?

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoURISuccess, onFail, { quality: 50,
            destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI, 
            correctOrientation: true });
```

Please help me.Thanks in Advance

Comment: create a imageview and pass the taken photo to that view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To capture photo you need to use getPicture method and to stored photo on DCIM\Camera path you need to turn true saveToPhotoAlbum parameter.

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoURISuccess, onFail, { quality: 50,
        destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI, 
        saveToPhotoAlbum: true,
        correctOrientation: true });
```

Comment: Hey, when i use this piece it does't call camera. I'm using "cordova-plugin-media-capture-r0.3.3" plugin. Can you please clarify?

Comment: This solution was answer to the JavaH request, using "cordova-2.1.0".